# How to use Join and Where to return an IList?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How can I achieve a join and a where in C# MVC using something like Linq or EF Join?

This is the equivalent SQL I am trying to achieve.

```
select * from promotion P
JOIN PromotionsClaimed PC
on PC.PromotionId = P.objectid
where PC.userId = @USERID
```

This method should return a list of the promotions for the user. First, I get a list of all of the promotions, then I get the composite list of claimed promotions for the user. This is what I have so far.

```
    public IList<Promotion> GetRewardsForUser(string userId)
    {
        //a list of all available promotions
        IList<Promotion> promos =  _promotionLogic.Retrieve();

        //contains a list of Promotion.objectIds for that user
        IList<PromotionsClaimed> promosClaimed = _promotionsClaimedLogic.RetrieveByCriteria(t => t.userId == userId);

        //should return a list of the Promotion name and code for the rewards claimed by user, but a complete list of Promotion entities would be fine
        var selectedPromos =
            from promo in promos
            join promoClaimed in promosClaimed on promo.objectId equals promoClaimed.PromotionId
            select new { PromoName = promo.Name, PromoCode = promo.Code };

        return selectedPromos;
    }
```

I realize there are a lot of problems here. I'm trying to learn Linq and Entity Framework, but I don't know how to add the where clause to an IList or if there is an easier way to accomplish this.

It seems to me like there would be a way to filter the promotion list where it contains the `Promotion.objectId` in the `promosClaimed` list, but I don't know the syntax.

Comment: There is a lot of SQL in this MVC tagged  question.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with MVC

Comment: There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking questions which have their answers there. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Comment: @JohnSaunders - that's not at all conducive to what StackOverflow is about. Had the OP had shown lack of effort, or you had've posted a more specific article/document section - fair enough, but he's been specific enough about his problem - and you've posted the whole C# programming guide. Not constructive at all.

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at the guide, and read the Linq getting started. It is still not clear how to combine a join and a where. Also, I'm looking for guidance if I am headed down the right track.

Comment: I'm making sure the OP knows where to find the manual, which I _do_ believe has the answer to his question. I've been surprised how many people don't know where to find the manual.

Comment: I just Google "linq join where" and the front page has a tonne of examples.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - well, of course it does. Most standard C# questions (i.e. questions not about non-third-party libraries) can be derived from the docs. But you're not taking into account the fact he's learning, or the context in which he's trying to apply it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - please provide a link that's specific to the relevant section then.

Comment: I thought the question of where to put the "where" was pretty straightforward, and wanted to make sure he simply didn't know where to look.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx. And the `select` has to be last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public IList<Promotion> GetRewardsForUser(string userId)
{
    //a list of all available promotions
    IList<Promotion> promos =  _promotionLogic.Retrieve();

    //contains a list of Promotion.objectIds for that user
    IList<PromotionsClaimed> promosClaimed = _promotionsClaimedLogic.RetrieveByCriteria(t => t.userId == userId);

    //should return a list of the Promotion name and code for the rewards claimed by user, but a complete list of Promotion entities would be fine
    var selectedPromos =
        (from promo in promos
        join promoClaimed in promosClaimed on promo.objectId equals promoClaimed.PromotionId
        select new { PromoName = promo.Name, PromoCode = promo.Code }).ToList();

    return selectedPromos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
public IList<Promotion> GetRewardsForUser(string userId)
{
    //contains a list of Promotion.objectIds for that user
    IList<PromotionsClaimed> promosClaimed = _promotionsClaimedLogic
        .RetrieveByCriteria(t => t.userId == userId);

    var promotionIds = promosClaimed.Select(p => p.PromotionId).ToList();

    IList<Promotion> promos = _promotionLogic.Retrieve()
        .Where(p => promotionIds.Contains(p.objectId))
        .Select(p => new { PromoName = p.Name, PromoCode = p.Code });

    return selectedPromos;
}
```

The claimed promotions should be already filtered by a user so this *should* possibly work.

Comment: I believe the OP wanted it in LINQ query syntax.

Comment: Not necessarily Linq. My goal is to return an IList of promotion that contains the name and code to display.

Comment: @User970008 I don't understand to be honest why your code sample does not work as you want. To me it seems like it should be doing what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I get the error "cannot implicitly convert type " IEnumerable to IList. Can you use Contains on IList?

Comment: @User970008 (and JakubHolovsky - note IList<> on left side, too): just add `.ToList()` at the end of `.Select(p => new { PromoName = p.Name, PromoCode = p.Code });`

Comment: Adding  .Select(p => new { PromoName = p.Name, PromoCode = p.Code }).ToList(); still throws cannot convert IEnum to IList

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're using entity framework? Or are you just trying to do join of two collections?

Because if you are using EF, you're thinking the wrong way. In the entity the proper way is to use include, for example:

```
public DbSet<promotion > promotion { get; set; }

public DbSet<PromotionsClaimed> PromotionsClaimed{ get; set; }

Context.promotion.Include(o => o.PromotionsClaimed).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == USERID);
```

If you need only join two collection using linq, you can do that.

```
var userId = 1;
var test =
        (
            from p in promos 
            join pc in promosClaimed  on p.objectid equals pc.PromotionId 
            where pc.userId == userId
            select p
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: I use EF to populate the Entity. Then there is a custom framework for the Unity Interface. I am just trying to get the list of promotions the the user has claimed. On your second example, none of those vars exist in context. I tried replacing with my list objects, but the error says PromotionsClaimed is being used like a variable.

Comment: What about using Retrieve().Join? I get stuck on the function syntax for the key in that signature if you think that could work.

Comment: PromotionsClaimed is being used like a variable ... Because I don't put the name of your list. It was an example, now edited and put the exact name of your list see there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just to add your condition to your code? Like:

```
var selectedPromos =
    from promo in promos
    join promoClaimed in promosClaimed on promo.objectId equals promoClaimed.PromotionId
    where promosClaimed.UserId == userId
    select new { PromoName = promo.Name, PromoCode = promo.Code };
```

That should work or I just didn't understand you

Comment: I did try that, but the problem is the IList. Converting IEnum to IList.

Comment: If you really need IList there, you can do .ToList(). If not - you can change the return type to IEnumerable. It depends on your app design